# Avoiding Multiple Routes for Different Languages

Tags: laravel, translation, laravel-7

I'm translating my site into different languages. By the default, the language will be English, which I'm using the following route to return the "welcome" view:

```
Route::get('welcome', function ()
{
    return view('welcome');
});
```

For my other languages, I'm using this other route:

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Is there any way I can combine those two routes into one? For example, if the route is "welcome" or "welcome/en", return the "welcome" view in English, the default language.

However,  if the route is "welcome/fr", the "welcome" view should be returned in French.

I'm going to have hundreds of routes so I would love being able to combine my routes.

Comment: there is such a thing as "optional" route parameters

Comment: Could it be done another way?

Comment: did you read the routing docs and see the part about "optional" route parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default language for your application is stored in the `config/app.php` configuration file. You may modify this value to suit the needs of your application. You may also change the active language at runtime using the `setLocale` method on the `App` facade:

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    if (! in_array($locale, ['en', 'es', 'fr'])) {
        abort(400);
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```

You may configure a "fallback language", **which will be used when the active language does not contain a given translation string**. Like the default language, the fallback language is also configured in the `config/app.php` configuration file:

```
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter, but make the presence of that route parameter optional. You may do so by placing a `?` mark after the parameter name. Make sure to give the route's corresponding variable a default value:

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale?}', function ($locale = null) {
    //
});
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the Laravel translation docs, but it doesn't answer the question about if there's a way to fallback to the default language of English if the route is "welcome" and no locale is provided in the route without using multiple Route::get calls.

Comment: The bold text is the answer, if no parameters are provided then the default will be obtained. I have edited my answer in case you get an error with the required parameter.

Comment: Laravel optional route parameter and PHP default function parameter was the key. ¡Muchas gracias! 